# Не работает pyautogui.moveTo()

Tags: python, pyautogui

Я писал код на заказ с помощью библиотеки `pyautogui` который должен найти на экране точку `x` навестись туда курсором, нажать и продолжить поиск так же. После я через программу TeamViewer скинул код в формате .py и попробовал его запустить, все сработало кроме функции которая должна была двигать мышкой -- `pyautogui.moveTo(win, 0.9)` (перед этим на моем пк все работало).
Вот часть кода:

```
import sys
import pyautogui

win = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Путь к скрину')
if win != None:
   pyautogui.moveTo(win, None, 0.9)
   print('Текст.')
   pyautogui.click(win)
else:
   sys.exit('Текст.')
   pass
```

Comment: TeamViewer ведь захватил мышь.

Comment: Переключитесь в режим только просмотр, и попросите запустить скрипт.